# What is the name of this function?

Tags: functions

What is the name of the following function (if there is one)?

$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x & \text{ if } -1 \leq x \leq 1\\
\frac 1x & \text{ if } x < -1 \text{ or } x >1\\
\end{cases}
$$

If this function has a name, how is it usually denoted?

Comment: Perhaps the context where you came across this might help...

Comment: I've never seen the function in any particular context.  I was trying to find a function so that for numbers $a$ and $b$ greater than 0: $f(\frac{a}{b})$ is always less than or equal to 1;  $f(\frac{a}{b})$ is largest when $a=b$; $f(\frac{a}{b})$ is increasing when b>a; $f(\frac{a}{b})$ is decreasing when a>b.

Comment: Why would you expect it to have a name?  
It's equal to  $\min(1, x^2)/x$ (except for $x=0$).

Comment: This function seems like it would be useful in many cases. Another way of writing the function: For numbers $a$ and $b$,  $f(\frac{a}{b})=\text{min}(\frac{a}{b},\frac{b}{a})$. Isn't it often that a ratio less than one is needed, rather than the ratio's inverse?

Comment: $\mathrm{sgn}(x)e^{-|\log(|x|)|}$ ?

Answer (score 5):

If there doesn't exist a standard name, I'd call it the "left one-right one-identity, alter-inverse" function on the reals.  The "left one-right one identity" part means that from the "left one" $(-1)$ to "the right one" the function matches that of the identity function on the reals.  The "alter-inverse" means "otherwise we have the inverse" (in Latin alter means "other"), since $1/x$ comes as the inverse function from the reals without 0 to the reals without 0.  The function maps to $[-1, 1]$ which under real-number multiplication forms a commutative monoid [$([-1, 1], \ast)$ is the commutative monoid] with annihilator of $0$, just like the reals do.  Have you found an inverse for your function?